# Moving Data To Object Within Array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a function called calc that runs some calculations and then pushes the results of these calculations to the object within the array surveyResults. After these calculations have been done, I then insert and render HTML into the DOM that pulls data to display from the array surveyResult.

After this, I have an object called chartResults that creates a chart with chart.js. I want to update the 'data' array that's inside the datasets array that's within chartResults object. I want to update it using the data for yearOneSaving, yearTwoSaving etc.

How would I do this? chartResults[2].data = yearOneSaving; and then repeat 10 times?

Edited to add - HTML and CSS so you can see how it works. Enter any number for each box expect 'system monthly payment' must = 26.26 and 'monthly gas payment' = 35. You can now see the chart generate when you click calculate

```js
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector('.card-wrapper-results');

let surveyResults = [
    {
        savings: 10.23,
        price: 35.84,
        priceEnd: 20.2
    }
];

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

function calc(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do the calculations.
    let gas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let boilerPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let smartSaving;
    let result;
    let totalSaving;
    smartSaving = gas * 0.2;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    totalSaving = smartSaving + gasSaving;
    result = boilerPrice - totalSaving;
    surveyResults[0].savings = totalSaving;
    surveyResults[0].price = boilerPrice;
    surveyResults[0].priceEnd = result;

    //Calculations For Chart Data.
    yearOneSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03;
    yearTwoSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearThreeSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearFourSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearFiveSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearSixSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearSevenSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    yearEightSavings = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    YearNineSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
    YearTenSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;

    // Generate HTML to show the chart in.
    let displayResults = surveyResults.map(
        (item) => `
    <div class="card2-results">
      <h1>Scrappage Payment</h1>
      <p class="job-title">Vaillant EcoTech Plus</p>
      <h2 class="about-h2">£507.23</h2>
      <ul class="about-payment">
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> AAA+ Rated Vaillant Ecotech Plus</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 10 Year Guaranty</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Big Gas Bill Savings</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Which Boiler Of The Year</li>
      </ul>
    
      <a href="" class="btn-results">30% Lower Gas Bill</a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="card2-results">
       <h1>Smart Allowance</h1>
       <p class="job-title">Hive Smart Heating</p>
       <h2 class="about-h2">
        £201.14
       </h2>
       <ul class="about-payment">
       <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Gen 3 Smart Heating System</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 10 Year Guaranty</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Big Gas Bill Savings</li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Phone App Controls</li>
        </ul>

        <a href="" class="btn-results">18% Lower Gas Bill</a>

            </div>
            
    <div class="card3-chart">
      <h1>Yearly Gas Savings</h1>
      <p class="job-title">Gen 3 Smart Heating</p>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card2-results">
    <h1>Monthly Payment </h1>
    <p class="job-title">EcoTech Plus</p>
    <h2 class="about-h2">
     £${item.price.toFixed(2)}
    </h2>
    <ul class="about-payment">
     <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Supply & Installation RRP £3699.00</li>
     <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Total Scrappage Payment £708.37</li>
     <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Net Price £2991.63</li>
     <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Hive Smart Heating System Included</li>
        </ul>
            <a href="" class="btn-results">£708.37 Saving</a>
        </div>
    
    <div class="card2-results">
      <h1>Monthly Gas Savings</h1>
      <p class="job-title">Instant Savings</p>
      <h2 class="about-h2">£${item.savings.toFixed(2)}</h2>
      <ul class="about-payment">
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Start Saving Straightaway</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 30% Saving From EcoTech Plus</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 18% Saving From Hive Smart Heating</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Hive Smart Heating System Included</li>
      </ul>
    
      <a href="" class="btn-results">1st Year £336</a>
    </div>
    
       <div class="card3">
            
            
                <h1>Net Installation Payment</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Installation Price With Gas Savings</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    £${item.priceEnd.toFixed(2)} pcm
                </h2>
                <div class="trust-logos">
                    <!-- trustpilot logo-->
                    <div class="trustpilot-container">
                        <img src="./img/trustpilot.png" class="trustpilot" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- which logo-->
                    <div class="which-container">
                        <img src="./img/which.png" class="which" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!--Gas Safe Logo-->
                    <div class="gas-container">
                        <img src="./img/Gas-Safe-Registered.png" class="gas" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- FCA logo-->
                    <div class="fca-container">
                        <img src="./img/fca-logo-social-media.jpg" class="fca" alt="">
                    </div>
            
               
            
            </div>
            <a href="" class="btn-results-approved">Installation Approved</a>


        </div>
    
  `
    );

    // Canvas element exists after this line.
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = displayResults;

    // Now the myChart element is in the DOM, select it.
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    // Create a new chart.
    let chartResults = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [ 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10' ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Savings Per Year £',
                    data: [ 342, 410, 443, 501, 557, 602, 673, 702, 764, 823 ],
                    backgroundColor: '#168ecf'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {}
    });
}
```

```css
/* Survery Section Start */

.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

.thebutton {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Calculation Results Start */

.section-results {
    margin-top: 6rem;
}

.results-h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.fa-plus-square {
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: #168ecf;
}

.uk-market-title {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.uk-market {
    color: #24272b;
    text-align: center;
}

.heading::after {
    content: "";
    width: 10rem;
    height: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

.card-wrapper-results {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card2-results {
    width: 35rem;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    box-shadow: .5rem .5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card3 {
    width: 74rem;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    box-shadow: .5rem .5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card3-chart {
    width: 74rem;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    box-shadow: .5rem .5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.profile-image2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin-top: -7rem;
    z-index: 999;
}

.card2-results .card3 h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #333;
    margin: 1.5rem;
}

.job-title-results {
    color: #777;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: -1rem;
}

.about-results {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.about-h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.about-payment {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    list-style: none;
    color: #333;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.fa-times {
    color: #c41a0e;
}

.fa-check {
    color: green;
}

.btn-results {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 25rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-results-approved {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.strike {
    color: red;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-red {
    background-color: #c41a0e;
}

.btn-green {
    background-color: green;
}

.card2 .btn:hover {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    box-shadow: .5rem .5rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card2 .btn:active {
    transform: translateY(0);
    box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .card-wrapper-results {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .card2-results {
        margin: 2rem;
    }
}

/* Calculation Results End */
```

```html
   <!-- Survery Start -->
   <section class="survery">
       <div class="survery-title">
           <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
       </div>
        <form action="">
        <div class="survery-questions">
                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Supplier" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Meter Serial No." class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="email-form">
                    <input  placeholder="Monthly Gas Spend" class="home-email-footer" id="gas" required>
                </div>

                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Monthly Payment" class="home-phone-footer" id="price" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Bathrooms" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Radiators" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Size Required (Kw)" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Residents" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="thebutton">
                    <button class="btn-calc" id="one">Calculate</button>
                
                </form>

            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
 <!-- Survery End-->

 <!-- Survey Results Start-->

<section class="section-results">
    <div class="container-results">
        <h1 class="heading">Your Scrappage Payment Offer</h1>
        <div class="card-wrapper-results">
            <div class="card2-results">


                <h1>Scrappage Payment </h1>
                <p class="job-title">Vaillant EcoTech Plus</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    £507.23
                </h2>
                <ul class="about-payment">
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> AAA+ Rated Vaillant Ecotech Plus</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 10 Year Guaranty</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Big Gas Bill Savings</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Which Boiler Of The Year</li>
                

                </ul>

                <a href="" class="btn-results">30% Lower Gas Bill</a>

            </div>



            <div class="card2-results">


                <h1>Smart Allowance</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Hive Smart Heating</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    £201.14
                </h2>
                <ul class="about-payment">
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Gen 3 Smart Heating System</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 10 Year Guaranty</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Big Gas Bill Savings</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Phone App Controls</li>
                
                
                </ul>

                <a href="" class="btn-results">18% Lower Gas Bill</a>

            </div>

            <div class="card3">
            
            
                <h1>Yearly Gas Savings</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Gen 3 Smart Heating</p>
                <canvas id="myChart">
                    
                </canvas>
            
            </div>

            <div class="card2-results">
            
            
                <h1>Monthly Payment </h1>
                <p class="job-title">EcoTech Plus</p>
            <h2 class="about-h2">
                £35.82
            </h2>
            <ul class="about-payment">
                <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Supply & Installation RRP £3699.00</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Total Scrappage Payment £708.37</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Net Price £2991.63</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Hive Smart Heating System Included</li>
            
            
            </ul>
            
                <a href="" class="btn-results">£708.37 Saving</a>
            
            </div>
            
            
            
            <div class="card2-results">
            
            
                <h1>Monthly Gas Savings</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Instant Savings</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    £28.02
                </h2>
                <ul class="about-payment">
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Start Saving Straightaway</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 30% Saving From EcoTech Plus </li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 18% Saving From Hive Smart Heating</li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Hive Smart Heating System Included</li>
                
                
                </ul>
            
                <a href="" class="btn-results">1st Year £336</a>
            
            </div>
            
            <div class="card3">
            
            
                <h1>Net Installation Payment</h1>
                <p class="job-title">Installation Price With Gas Savings</p>
                <h2 class="about-h2">
                    £7.80 pcm
                </h2>
                <div class="trust-logos">
                    <!-- trustpilot logo-->
                    <div class="trustpilot-container">
                        <img src="./img/trustpilot.png" class="trustpilot" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- which logo-->
                    <div class="which-container">
                        <img src="./img/which.png" class="which" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!--Gas Safe Logo-->
                    <div class="gas-container">
                        <img src="./img/Gas-Safe-Registered.png" class="gas" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <!-- FCA logo-->
                    <div class="fca-container">
                        <img src="./img/fca-logo-social-media.jpg" class="fca" alt="">
                    </div>
            
               
            
            </div>
            <a href="" class="btn-results-approved">Installation Approved</a>


        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


 <!-- Survey Results End-->



 <!-- JS Scripts Start -->
 
 <script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-s+xg36jbIujB2S2VKfpGmlC3T5V2TF3lY48DX7u2r9XzGzgPsa6wTpOQA7J9iffvdeBN0q9tKzRxVxw1JviZPg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- JS Scripts ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe use a for loop with `Math.pow` for 0.03? :)

Comment: Don't forget to add the HTML in the snippet so that `document.getElementById('one');`  (and other document element references) will work.

Comment: I've updated to add the html and css. Responsiveness hasn't been done yet so please view in full browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some variables and use those instead of hardcoding data....

So.....

```
// Canvas element exists after this line.
resultsContainer.innerHTML = displayResults;

// Now the myChart element is in the DOM, select it.
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

// Create a new chart.
let chartResults = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [ 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10' ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Savings Per Year £',
                data: [ 342, 410, 443, 501, 557, 602, 673, 702, 764, 823 ],
                backgroundColor: '#168ecf'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

becomes something like.....

```
var savingsperyear = [ 342, 410, 443, 501, 557, 602, 673, 702, 764, 823 ];
// Canvas element exists after this line.
resultsContainer.innerHTML = displayResults;

// Now the myChart element is in the DOM, select it.
let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

// Create a new chart.
let chartResults = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [ 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10' ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Savings Per Year £',
                data: savingsperyear,
                backgroundColor: '#168ecf'
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {}
});
```

(that keeps the data on load of the page...)

Then, to update it, in your calc function

```
yearOneSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03;
yearTwoSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03;
yearThreeSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
yearFourSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
yearFiveSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
yearSixSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
yearSevenSaving = totalSaving * 12 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03 * 0.03;
......
```

you need to set the array again...

```
// first, empty the array
savingsperyear.length = 0; 
// then, fill it with what you need (note I got a bit lost with your code, but this should get you going.....! :)
savingsperyear.push(yearOneSaving);
savingsperyear.push(yearTwoSaving);
savingsperyear.push(yearThreeSaving);
// etc..... (there are other ways to do this, I'm just showing it step by step)
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error savingsPerYear is undefined in the console

Comment: put the var savingsperyear at the top of the function (or outside the function) - in JS you need to declare your variables before using them.